# Max size for BluetoothRemoteGATTCharacteristic.writeValueWithResponse()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ubuntu, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I'm using Web Bluetooth on Chrome to send data to a BLE device running micropython using the following code...

```
var value = new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode(str);
for (i=0; i<value.byteLength; i+=self.DATA_BUFFER_SIZE) {
  await self.dataCharacteristic.writeValueWithResponse(value.slice(i, i + self.DATA_BUFFER_SIZE));
}
```

The micropython BLE device has its receive buffer set to 512 bytes, and on most computers, the above code works fine with `self.DATA_BUFFER_SIZE` set to 512 as well. But on one computer, I could not get the above code to work unless `self.DATA_BUFFER_SIZE` is reduced to 20. If set to anything higher than 20, `writeValueWithResponse()` will not complete. There are no error messages on the developer console, the `await` simply never completes.

Tested successfully with 512...

- Various macbooks
- Various Win 10 laptops
- Desktops and laptops running Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04
- Android phone
- Fire tablet

Failed unless set to 20...

- A single laptop running Ubuntu 22.04, Chrome 108.0.5359.124, Qualcomm atheros qca9377

Can anyone advice...

1. Is this a bug in Chrome / Linux qca9377 driver / hardware?
2. Are there any ways for me to detect the largest safe buffer size for writeValueWithResponse?

Comment: How does your micropython ble code look like?

Comment: Full code is here https://github.com/QuirkyCort/IoTy/blob/main/public/firmware/ioty/…, but it's a little long. I suppose the important bit is... `self._ble.gatts_set_buffer(self._handle_data, 512)`